# How do I prevent global namepace pollution in Javascript while at the same time avoiding YUICompressor warnings?

Tags: jquery, yui-compressor

I am using YUICompressor to compress my jQuery plugins. Initially I got a lot of warnings "Try to have only one var statement and one return per function", so I put all declarations at the top like in the following example:

```
        $.fn.myWidget = function () {

            var function1, function2, function3

            function1 = function () {

                // Do stuff

            };

            function2 = function () {

                // Do stuff

            };

            // This will be a global function
            function3 = function () {

                // Do stuff

            };

        };
```

In bigger plugins this becomes a code maintenance nightmare.

Let's say I add a function4, but I forget to add the variable declaration add the top, now I am actually creating a variable in the global window namespace.
If the plugin gets used multiple times on the page the global function gets overwritten.

Right now I am running the following script to check for global namespace pollution, but I was wondering if anybody has a better solution

```
        for (var f in window) {
            if (window.hasOwnProperty(f)) {
                $("#debug").append(f + " " + " Type: " + typeof window[f] + "<br>");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to declare the functions in a map form, it removes the problem of separating the declaration from the code, ie.

```
$.fn.myWidget = function () {

        var a, b, c, //internal vars
         myWidget = {
            function1: function () {

            // Do stuff

            },
            function2: function () {

            // Do stuff

            },
            function3: function () {

            // Do stuff

            }
        }

        return myWidget;

    };
```

<strike>Why do you have a global function in your widget? Doesn't that defeat the purpose of the widget? Just put it outside the declaration of the widget.</strike>
Reread the question, yeah, using this style also eliminates accidentally making a global function.

Also, the jQuery [DOCs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) provide a lot of good advice for doing it correctly